# How to use tune2fs?

Tags: files, filesystems, ext4

I want to adjust the time interval between ext2, ext3 and ext4 filesystem checks to 180 days?

I know that I have to use `tune2fs -i 180` but I am not sure about the arguments

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
tune2fs -i180d <block device>
```

The default unit is days, so `180` will be interpreted the same as `180d` but [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=EIBTI).

For example:

```
tune2fs -i180d /dev/sda3
```

Make sure you always use `tune2fs` when the filesystem is **unmounted**!